# SKIP/OFFSET/ScanRange of rows in AWS S3 Select

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I wonder if anyone figured out how to skip rows in [S3 Select](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.select_object_content)?

```
SELECT S.* FROM s3object S SKIP 100 LIMIT 200
--or
SELECT * from s3object s LIMIT 5, 10
--or
SELECT * from s3object s limit 5 OFFSET 10
```

It looks like you can [limit number of records returned](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html#s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-limit)

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = bucket
file_name = file

sql_stmt = """SELECT S.* FROM s3object S LIMIT 10"""


req = s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Key=file,
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    Expression=sql_stmt,
    InputSerialization = {'CSV': {'FileHeaderInfo': 'USE'}},
    OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}},
)
```

There was also a [request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3998) made to add OFFSET/SKIP to s3api,
but it was closed.

Also you can specify [ScanRange](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_SelectObjectContent.html#AmazonS3-SelectObjectContent-request-ScanRange) in bytes, but what happens if object is compressed?

Is it range in bytes of compressed object or uncompressed?

If uncompressed how does S3 Select handle partial records?

Update: You cannot use ScanRange on `gzip` file:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
>   (UnsupportedScanRangeInput) when calling the SelectObjectContent
>   operation: Scan range queries are not supported on objects with type
>   GZIP.